# jQuery not firing until something has occured on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal that I am wanting to show right before a function is fired and then I want to hide the modal as soon as the function has finished. My problem is the modal will not launch unless I do something on the page first, like an alert. I will post my code below:

```
$j('#myModal').modal('show');
SearchNew(searchParameters);

SearchOld(searchParameters);    
$j('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

The above launches the modal and hides it really quick right after the last function is completed.

The below works, because I have an alert that is an action on the page. It then opens the modal correctly and closes it after the last function is complete.

```
$j('#myModal').modal('show');
alert('test');
SearchNew(searchParameters);

SearchOld(searchParameters);    
$j('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? These functions are launched on click.

Comment: So your code is running as expected, isn't it? It stops when you launch an alert, because an alert requires user interaction before the other code is executed...

Comment: No, I dont want to have to show an alert for the modal to launch. I need to be able to show the modal without an alert launching... I want to show modal wile data is loading and once finished loading, I dismiss it.

Comment: The issue might be that the time between "showing" and "hiding" the modal is too small (the functions are too fast).

Comment: @Code, I know what you want, but I explained why it is happening. That is what you are asking.

Comment: @Kairat the functions are actually pretty slow... 5 seconds or so

Comment: @Mikey sure... how can I achieve what my expected outcome is?

Comment: @Code you probably doing an asynchrounous request, but javascript is single threaded. If you want to execute scripts after a request is returned you should look at resolving the promise https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: Did you write your question correctly? `The above launches the modal and hides it really quick right after the last function is completed` -- is that what is actually happening, or what you want to happen? If it is actually what is happening, how do you want it to be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example:

(1) Displays modal upon button click

(2) Imitates running a function (using setTimeout)

(3) Closes the modal when function (e.g. timeout) completed

The `setTimeout` function takes the place of the callback to the function you are running -- which is where you close the modal.

```js
$('#myModal').modal('hide'); //initialize

$('button').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#msg').html('The function is updating this div').show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    },2000);
});
```

```css
* {position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;}
button{cursor:pointer;}
#msg{position:absolute;width:150px;height:100px;font-size:1.5rem;background:wheat;color:darkcyan;border:1px solid orange;display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button id="go">Click Me</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="msg"></div>
```

---

Is this, in essence, how you are doing things? If not, advise on differences that must be accommodated.